# What are units of quantum field (or creation and annihilation) operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, operators, solid-state-physics, dimensional-analysis

Let us have a free particle Hamiltonian given as
$$
\hat{H} =  \sum_{k}\mathcal{E}_k c_k^\dagger c_k \quad ; \quad \mathcal{E}_k=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}  
$$
unit of $\hbar$ are $J\cdot s$, the units of mass are $kg=J\cdot m^{-2}\cdot s^2$ and unit of $k=m^{-1}$, so over all units of $\mathcal{E}_k\equiv [\mathcal{E}_k]$ are
$$
[\hat H]=[\mathcal{E}_k]\cdot [unit\; of\; c_k^\dagger c_k]=\frac{J^2s^2}{Jm^{-2}s^2}\cdot m^{-2}\cdot [unit\; of\; c_k^\dagger c_k]=J\cdot [unit\; of\; c_k^\dagger c_k] \tag{1}
$$
As we know that units of Hamiltonian are $J$, so we can say that this way $ [ c_k^\dagger c_k]$ does not have any units.

But now let's write Hamiltonian in quantum fields with help of Fourier transform:
$$
c_k^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\int dr e^{ikr} \Psi^\dagger_r \quad; \quad c_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\int dr' e^{-ikr'} \Psi^\dagger_{r'} \tag{2}
$$
so,
$$
\hat{H} =  \frac{1}{V}\int d^3r \int d^3r' e^{ik(r-r')}\sum_{k}\mathcal{E}_k \Psi_r^\dagger \Psi_{r'} \tag{4}
$$
Here $V$ is a volume that has units of $m^3$. The unit of $r$ and $r'$ is meter $m$. Overall unit of $[\hat H]$ are now
$$
[\hat H]=\frac{1}{m^3}\cdot m^3 \cdot m^3\cdot[\mathcal{E}_k]\cdot [units\; of\;  \Psi^\dagger \Psi]
$$
$$
[\hat H]=J\cdot m^3  [units\; of\;  \Psi^\dagger \Psi] \tag{5}
$$
this way to have the unit of Hamiltonian $J$, the unit of $\Psi^\dagger \Psi$ should be $m^{-3}$.
So my question is, why does quantum operators in $k$-space $c_k^\dagger $ have no units but in real space $\Psi^\dagger(r)$ they have unit of $m^{-3/2}$? Is it because of the way we define Fourier transform?

Comment: @Jakob no. If we look at equation $(1)$, $c_k$ is unitless. But in equation $(5)$, $\Psi(r)$ should have units of $m^{-3/2}$

Comment: Sorry, yes, I misread the equation $(2)$. However, from there we can see read off the 'units' of $\Psi(r)$. BTW: The question in the title does not really match the question at the end... *That* the units of $\Psi$ are given like that can be seen from equation $(2)$, tho.

Comment: Your formula (1) is incorrect, there should be a momentum-space integral in there, not a sum; and the momentum-space measure $d^3 p$ is not dimensionless.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov If you're working with a finite volume (and periodic boundary conditions) the sum is fine.